# DirectX with c++ in web development

Tags: c++, web-applications, directx

I wonder if it possible to make a game by c++ with directx(in GFX) so that it could be put in my web (php , asp.net, java or other I don't care about the web language or technology, you chose one for me) and be played online or I have to change something directx or C++.
if it possible tell me how?
thnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean browser based, I'm not sure it's possible with C++. You might want to look into [webGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).

If you're feeling very adventurous, I am aware of an open source project that is essentially a .NET to JS compiler. You can check it out on github [here](https://github.com/kevingadd/JSIL)

If you mean "online" as in a MMO type of game, or a game that is played over a network, (but not in a browser), then obviously it is quite possible, I don't know the specific libraries you'd use though.

Comment: browser based applications with C++ are possible with Google Native Client, but its still doubtable that Google NaCl will get popular... especially now, since WebGL is here..